# How can I solve the error "Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project" in eas build command ios?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I'm trying to build my Expo iOS app using the command `eas build -p ios` , some days ago I was able to do it without problem, after that I modified my project by adding Apple authentication using the `expo-apple-authentication` package, it works in the Expo Go app but when I try to build it the process stops in the `Run fastlane` step trowing the rror `Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project`.

Not sure if this is related to the Apple Store portal outage eas is facing at the moment of writing this question, I picked `No` after eas build prompts to login into my Apple account, if I picked `Yes` the build didn't start.

I hope you can help me with this.